# Strange behavior of $\sin(x^3)$ and $\tan(x^3)$

Tags: trigonometry, chaos-theory

I noticed this behavior a long time ago and never really figured this out but if you take the $\sin$ or $\cos$ or $\tan$ etc. of a cubic polynomial you get a very strange and erratic behavior. It seems to have no easily explainable pattern and I'm not sure why. The function is still smooth but the successive derivatives grow ever larger. My best guess is that because the derivatives keep growing larger and larger but are still periodic you get this behavior because the every more violent derivatives keep canceling each other out.

Is this an example of a simple chaotic system? What features of these functions make it behave so erratically. Can I do this with other kinds of periodic functions?

In short, why does this function behave so erratically?

Comment: Essentially, these functions are not periodic

Comment: ... but it's not "chaotic".  It's just that you're looking at it at different time-scales.  In a chaotic dynamical system, the dynamics is time-invariant or periodic.

Comment: Fun fact: $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^3)\, dx$ actually converges, because the ever-increasing oscillation causes a lot of cancellation in the partial integral $\int_0^t \sin(x^3)\, dx$; the latter is stable enough to converge as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: This is *not* an example of a chaotic system; it's just a graph of a function with oscillations whose rate increases (as Withner explained nicely). Chaotic systems arise when you construct *dynamics*, perhaps by iteration or via a differential equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When plotting rapid oscillating functions on graphical calculators one often run into problems with the calculator using a too coarse sampling of the point making the plot look very erratic (the fairly large pixel-size on these calculators does not help either). As OP mentioned below; his plots looks very different from the one I present here so this is likely the source of the apparent "chaotic" behavior.

---

The period of $\sin(x)$ is $2\pi$ so starting at a given value $x$ we have that $\sin(x^3)$ completes one oscillation when reaching $x + \Delta x$ where 
$$(x+\Delta x)^3 - x^3 = 2\pi \implies\Delta x \approx \frac{2\pi}{3x^2}$$
for large $x$. We see that $\Delta x$ becomes smaller and smaller as $x$ grows so the function oscillates more and more rapidly as we increase $x$. This in turn implies very large derivatives for large $x$. We can also show this by computing the derivatives exactly

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x^3) = 3x^2\cos(x^3)$$

The graph of this will be rapid oscillations contained within the envelope of $\pm 3x^2$:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

You can get this behavior with any type of periodic function $f(x)$ by considering $f(g(x))$ where $g(x)$ grows faster than $x$. For example taking $g(x)=e^x$ gives even more rapid oscillations than for $g(x) = x^3$. Here is a comparison of $\sin(e^{2x})$ and $\sin(x^3)$:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

Comment: So as another note it would appear that the sampling technique of the graphing calculator I was using was to blame. Your graphs look more like what I would imagine this function should have looked like. After closer inspection it is the sampling frequency that seems to have caused the behavior.

Comment: @Jake very well thought! I have also experieced this kind of behaviour before, and I never thought it could be the sampling frequency, but it makes a lot of sense! Thanks for this question. By the way I think this answer would be further improved if it included a paragraph mentioning this effect.

Comment: @Winther by the way, may I ask which software you used for these graphs?

Comment: @Hamsteriffic I use [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) (the same math engine that is behind Wolfram Alpha). It's very nice for these types of things but it can be quite expensive unless you are a student.

Comment: @Jake That is a common problem. I think one can adjust the sampling frequency (atleast this was possible on my old Texas Instrument calculator). Another thing one can do if experiencing this (and trying to figure out if it's real) is to try plotting it over a zoomed-in region and see if the plot looks smoother.

Comment: @Winther thank you! In fact I do happen to be an undergraduate student. I did not know they gave special prices to students though. I will investigate it further. Thank you!

Comment: @Winther. Yea that's what made me notice it. As I zoomed in a bit the graph changed completely and then again it changed but after that it stayed the same. You can even start to see the sampeling issue in the last part of your sin(e^x) graph near the peaks. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Jake It's not a matter of sampling *frequency*. Rather, Mathematica uses an adaptive procedure to sample a function more frequently where it needs to. There are other tools that do this as well. [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) can give you a [nice graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/txwdxikucm) of this as well.